# docker system prune with filtering

Tags: docker

Would like to execute `docker system prune` but using filters to avoid deleting resources that have either one of 2 different labels.

Assume we would like `docker system prune` to exclude all resources with either one of these labels:

```
io.kubernetes.container.name=name-01
io.kubernetes.container.name=name-02
```

Running `docker system prune -f --volumes --filter "label!=io.kubernetes.container.name=name-01" --filter "label!=io.kubernetes.container.name=name-02"` will result in non of the resources being excluded since it seems that executing the command like this, would exclude resources that have both labels (AND instead of OR).

How could we execute `docker system prune` in such way where remove all resources except those matching **either** one of those labels?

Comment: You might find it easier adding a new label to containers that need to be preserved.

Comment: If adding an extra label would be the workaround, then I think adding it to the 2 "kind" of containers would be easier in our case. With that being said, docker system prune does more than cleaning containers, would that mean that we need to add that label also to the volumes/images/networks?

I had hopes in maybe the "--filter" accepting some sort of go templating to introduce a logical "OR" somehow.

Comment: If the container still exists, the associated image is not pruned. Same for volumes and networks that are still associated with a container.

Comment: I can't see how to do this safely, furthermore. Adding extra labels I guess would work if builds were mine or if I could control which builds are deployed in our envs. I created this issue, but as per what other similar issues were handled, I do not think it will get anywhere: https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/3557

Comment: If the images aren't built locally and you delete them, you'd just pull them again when needed. You do have control to add labels to networks and volumes.

Comment: Pulling again images would not solve the needs derived by the imposibility of more sofisticated filtering. It happens with kubernetes that issuing docker system prune, will trigger a re-run of so called init-containers. In some particular applications, this breaks the application regardless the presence (or lack of it) of the image.